# How to show that inter-arrival time of stochastic process has an exponential distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, poisson-process, exponential-distribution

Let $(Z_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be a stochastic proces defined by $Z_t = \max\{X_t , Y_t \}$ with $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ and $(Y_t)_{t \geq 0}$ independent Poisson processes with parameters $\lambda$ an $\mu$. How do I show that the first inter-arrival time of $(Z_t)_{t \geq 0}$ has an exponential distribution?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if $T_x,T_y,T_z$ are the first inter-arrival times of $X,Y,Z$ respectively, then $T_z=T_x\wedge T_y$, and using this you can compute $\mathbb{P}(T_z>t)$ for $t>0$.

Comment: I don't exactly understand how to conclude $T_z = T_x \wedge T_y$

Comment: @PhillipJones Z will jump for the first time when either $X$ jumps for the first time or $Y$ does. So the first time it jumps is the minimum of the two.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that you meant $Z_t = \min\{X_t,Y_t\}$ because otherwise the result is not true. In this case, denoting by $T_n^X$, $T_n^Y$, and $T_n^Z$ the $n^{\mathrm{th}}$ arrival time of $X_t$, $Y_t$, and $Z_t$, respectively, we have for each $t>0$
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(T_1^Z>t) &= \mathbb P(\min\{T_1^X,T_1^Y\}>t)\\
&= \mathbb P(T_1^X>t, T_1^Y>t)\\
&= \mathbb P(T_1^X>t)\mathbb P(T_1^Y>t)\\
&= e^{-\lambda t}e^{-\mu t}\\
&= e^{-(\lambda+\mu)t},
\end{align}
so that $T_1^Z$  has exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda+\mu$.